# Only repository name showing on the public link created by Github in my pages section

Tags: github

I am new to coding area, and started learning coding since last few days; I have completed some projects.

But, when I want to upload and live it on GitHub platform, it is just showing the repository name when going to the created link.

I manually uploaded 1 file of CSS and HTML each, its showing problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your projects set up as nested Git repository inside your main local repository, then you would see those subrespo root folder as links ([gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309), a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) indeed.

```
myProjects
  .git/
  project1
    .git/
  project2
   .git/
  ...
```

Make sure to create one GitHub repository per project.

You can do so from your workstation, using the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli), with [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create):

```
# create a remote repository from the current directory
gh repo create my-project --source=.
```